# form_submit codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter, form-submit

So I am having trouble with the form_submit in codeigniter. I have a controller named welcome with a method named email. Whenever I hit my submit button the page refreshes but then just appends ?firstname=&email=&message=&submit=Submit to my url but doesn't carry out the method. Any reason this may be happening?

below is my html code.

```
                        <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label>

                            <?php $this->load->helper("form"); ?>
                            <?php  echo validation_errors('<p class = "error">'); ?>
                            <?php echo form_open('welcome/email');

                            $data = array('type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control',        'name'=>'firstname');
                            echo form_input($data);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <?php
                            $data = array('type'=>'email','class'=>'form-control', 'name'=>'email');
                            echo form_input($data);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <?php
                            $data= array('type'=>'text','name'=>'message','class'=>'form-control','rows'=>7);
                            echo form_textarea($data);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right">



                        <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg" action="welcome/email">Submit</button> -->
                        <?php

                        echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
                        echo form_close();
                        ?>
                        </div>
```

This is my controller

```
<?php /*if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');*/

    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {



     function index(){
        $this->load->view('index-sidebar');

    }


    function email(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Name', 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[200]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('message not sent');

        }

        else{
            $this->load->library('email');

            $this->email->from(set_value('email'),set_value('name'));
            $this->email->to("mhansen1989@gmail.com");
            $this->email->subject('tutoring');
            $this->email->message(set_value('message'));


            $this->email->send();

            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            $this->load->view('success');
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no action parameter in your form tag.how do you submit the form?

try this

```
<form action="<?= base_url().'welcome/email'?>" role="form" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks. I found it's because I declare a <form> in html format and did form_open as well. So just opened the form twice and didn't declare an action in the first one as you said. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

so here

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
        $this->load->view('message not sent');

    }
```

put in your correct view name where it says 'message not sent'

```
$this->load->helper("form");
```

load your helpers in the controller -- better yet do it config/autoload

and this

```
$data = array('type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','name'=>'firstname');
 echo form_input($data);
```

in the form you repeat $data over and over. technically it will work but its going to mess up at some point so make them different names

```
$first = array('type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','name'=>'firstname');
 echo form_input($first);
```

and you need something to show the values in the form again if the validation is false. check out http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

Comment: Thanks. I found it's because I declare a <form> in html format and did form_open as well. So just opened the form twice and didn't declare an action in the first one as you said. Thank you very much for the response. It's much appreciated. I had the form auto loaded already. I took your advice and still changed each $data name to its own.